# cross domain error jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to get data from another domain using ajax, this is my code :

```
(function($) {
var url = 'https://service';

$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'jsonp',

    success: function(json) {
       console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(e) {
       console.log("fail");
    }
});

})(jQuery);
```

I'm getting this error : 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz6zi.png)

Comment: It seems that the response doesn't have a valid jsonp data. Open the network tab and check it.

Comment: You can not just force a 3rd party site to give you jsonp unless they offer it. If they do not support CORS you can not request it from the clientside.

Comment: It does not seem to be a cross domain error...